# Why simple HTML page is not loading through Spring-MVC

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to display a simple Hello message through Spring-MVC.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SampleApplication</display-name>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>html/homepage.html</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

</web-app>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.itc" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/html/**" location="/html/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**homepage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here homepage.html is present in WEB-INF/html folder. I'm not getting any errors/exception.
I'm using Spring 4.0.6 version.
Any help on this?

Comment: add below line in spring-servlet.xml for view resolver    <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: @Vaibs I'm not using jsp file, I want to use html files. Still do I need to declare the viewresolver?

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the `ViewResolver` in the `Spring-servlet.xml`

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.itc" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/html/**" location="/html/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    //Add this..
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />  
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadHtml(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "homePage";
}
```